# create animation by scaling part of an image

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i would like to launch an animation that scales an image partially.

For example i have a ccsprite with a flower and when i touch that flower, i would like to create an animation when only its routs contract.

This could be done by creating an animation frame-by-frame (which takes much more time to be crated by the designer), but i was thinking about setting scale for a certain part of the image and animating it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use cocos2d effects to move part of a sprite 
try to use  Grid3D i think that is what you want
[check out the documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/40)